# Wordpress Menu not working on mobile

Tags: php, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I've just uploaded my first ever custom theme to a website of mine, everything was going great until I checked the website on my mobile and realised that when I click on the hamburger menu, nothing happened. Here is my website:

timothycdavis.co.uk

Here are the links to my [style.css](http://timothycdavis.co.uk/wp-content/themes/char-counter/style.css) file, my [bootstrap](http://timothycdavis.co.uk/wp-content/themes/char-counter/css/bootstrap.css) file.

And below are my functions.php file and header.php file

Functions.php:

```
// Register Custom Navigation Walker
require_once('wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php');

// Theme Support
function wpb_theme_setup(){
    // Nav Menu
    register_nav_menus(array(
      'primary' => __('Primary Menu ')
    ));
}

  add_action('after_setup_theme', 'wpb_theme_setup');

  add_action( 'wp_loaded', 'wpse248829_register_scripts' );
function wpse248829_register_scripts() {
    wp_register_script( 'character-counter-script-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/char-counter.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_register_script( 'tweet-counter', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/tweet-counter.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_register_script( 'title-tag-counter-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/char-counter/js/title-tag.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
    wp_register_script( 'description-counter-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/description-tag.min.js', array( 'jquery' ), false, true );
}

//Enqueue scripts/styles.
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse248829_enqueue_scripts' );
function wpse248829_enqueue_scripts() {
    // Load everywhere.
    wp_enqueue_style( 'style', get_stylesheet_uri() );

    // Probably not needed, because it was already specified as a dependency.
    // wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );

    // Only enqueue scripts/styles on static front page.
    if ( is_front_page() ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'character-counter-script-js' );
    }

    if ( is_page_template( 'tweet-template.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'tweet-counter' );
    }

    if ( is_page_template( 'title-tag-template.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'title-tag-counter-script' );
    }

    if ( is_page_template( 'description-tag-template.php' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'description-counter-script' );
    }
}

require get_template_directory() . '/inc/customizer.php';
```

Header.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-GB" prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns#">

<head>

  <meta charset="<?php bloginfo('charset'); ?>">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap Core CSS -->
  <link href="<?php bloginfo('template_url') ?>/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom Fonts -->
  <link href="http://timothycdavis.co.uk/wp-content/themes/char-counter/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300italic,400italic,600italic,700italic,800italic,400,300,600,700,800' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Merriweather:400,300,300italic,400italic,700,700italic,900,900italic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>


    <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/3.2.1/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Theme CSS -->


    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="/img/favicon.ico">

    <script src="//load.sumome.com/" data-sumo-site-id="63887403fa39b3ec361069237f61eca50baf36e10e2973ac54b998b5095b3bb2" async="async"></script>


    <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/html5shiv/3.7.0/html5shiv.js"></script>
        <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/libs/respond.js/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->

        <title><?php wp_title(''); ?></title>

        <?php wp_head(); ?>

</head>

<body itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage">

    <div id="wrapper" class="clearfix" itemprop="mainContentOfPage">

    <nav id="mainNav" class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
            <div class="navbar-header">
              <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                  <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                  <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>

                <?php if ( get_theme_mod( 'm1_logo' ) ) : ?>
                    <a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" id="site-logo" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home">

                    <img src="<?php echo get_theme_mod( 'm1_logo' ); ?>" alt="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>">

                    </a>

                  <?php else : ?>

                    <hgroup>
                        <h1 class="site-title"><a href="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr( get_bloginfo( 'name', 'display' ) ); ?>" rel="home"><?php bloginfo( 'name' ); ?></a></h1>
                        <p class="site-description"><?php bloginfo( 'description' ); ?></p>
                    </hgroup>

                <?php endif; ?>
          </div>

            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                  <?php
                wp_nav_menu( array(
                    'menu'              => 'primary',
                    'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                    'depth'             => 2,
                    'container'         => 'div',
                    'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                    'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                    'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                    'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                    'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
                );
            ?>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
```

Aplogies for my poorly written code in advance, and thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Bootstrap's JS file is commented out in HTML output.

Comment: @makshh I've fixed that now, but the menu still isn't working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting the following error in your js console:

> TypeError: $ is not a function

When I track it down, it is here:

> var initTop=new Array();;$("textarea").on("input",function ...etc

Do two things:

1. Be sure that your calls using jQuery syntax are only called after jQuery is available (for instance inside your existing `jQuery(document).ready(` call in that same js file)
2. Be sure that you can use `$()` syntax...your other calls seem to use `jQuery()` syntax meaning you may have [no conflict mode](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) turn on.

**UPDATE**

Okay, now that your JS error is fixed, your nav is loading.  Good job.  Next, you have a bit of a overzealous implementation of the nav.  Please note that in the HTML DOM, every `id=""` must have a unique value.

You will find that in your implementation the id `bs-example-navbar-collapse-1` is used two times.  If you only use it once, your nav will work just fine.  What's happening now is that your JavaScript is finding the first (since there is only supposed to be one), and while it's opening that one, the other one is left hidden.

See this video:

http://screencast.com/t/GdGHeL2U0yF

I believe this translates into the following code being what you want:

```
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <?php
        /* <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1"> NO */
            /* <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right"> NO */

            // now let the thing build itself and don't help

            wp_nav_menu( array(
                'menu'              => 'primary',
                'theme_location'    => 'primary',
                'depth'             => 2,
                'container'         => 'div',
                'container_class'   => 'collapse navbar-collapse',
                'container_id'      => 'bs-example-navbar-collapse-1',
                'menu_class'        => 'nav navbar-nav',
                'fallback_cb'       => 'wp_bootstrap_navwalker::fallback',
                'walker'            => new wp_bootstrap_navwalker())
            );

        /*    </ul> NO */
        /* </div>   NO */
        ?>
        <!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I'm quite new to jquery, so can you explain to me exactly what to do in order to fix this problem

Comment: Qualifying question, here, but did you write this bit of javascript starting, `$("textarea").on("input",function` ?  If not, it is being included improperly or your jQuery is set to [no conflict mode](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/) <-- follow that link.

Comment: Hmm, i'm not sure how to be more clear than I was in the solution.  Since `$` is not an object at the point at which that runs, it cannot be used.  You need to be sure that `$` is an object at the run time of that js that you wrote.  Do that using the 1. and 2. above.

Comment: Note, it may be as easy as using `jQuery` where you have `$`.

Comment: The error isn't happening anymore, but the menu still won't work

Comment: Gotcha, the lack of a unique id on your nav element is the issue.  Please see updated code snippet for the navbar-collapse in my **UPDATE**d post.

Comment: I honestly can't thank you enough for your help. Everything is working now!